# Xcode9 not work NSLog Swift in Simulator-System log

Tags: swift, xcode8, xcode9, nslog

I want to see log in Simulator-System log. 

Xcode9 not work but Xcode8 works.

I tried in Xcode9.2 beta but not work as well.

```
NSLog("\(message)")
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(message)`?

Comment: print not work in System log